# MVC Remote validation is adding model to url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, begincollectionitem

I have remote validation on a field and it fires but I get a 500 error saying the parameter is null at the controller method is null.  What is actually happening is the model name is added to the url, which makes it unable to find the method.

Example:

STUDENT model

```
    [Remote("CheckExistingStudent", "Student", AdditionalFields = "FirstName", ErrorMessage = "This student already exists!")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

For some reason the url created when the validation triggers is:

```
http://localhost:4855/Student/CheckExistingStudent?Student.LastName=Waters&Student.FirstName=Nigel
```

Notice the Student. in the URL.

I have tried a couple different method signatures:

```
    public JsonResult CheckExistingResource(string FIrstName, string LastName)

    public JsonResult CheckExistingResource(StudentModel model)
```

The first one returns the 500 error (null parameter).  The second one passing the Student model gets intot he method, but  the first & last are null.

I'm sure this is happening because I am using the Html.BeginCollectionItem helper to build a dynamic list so the user can enter multiple students on the same page. Part of the BCI helper is that it renames each field with a unique index.

So I dont think I can stop the url from having model. in it. Is it possible to have model. in the method parameter names? I tried, it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a model bind prefix is in order:

```
public JsonResult CheckExistingResource([Bind(Prefix="Student")]StudentModel model)
```